# Convert Uint8Array[n] into integer in node.js

Tags: node.js, type-conversion

I have a variable Uint8Arr of type Uint8Array[4].

```
Uint8Arr[0]=0x12;
Uint8Arr[1]=0x19;
Uint8Arr[2]=0x21;
Uint8Arr[3]=0x47;
```

I want to convert `Uint8Arr` into its equivalent integer which is `0x12192147` or `303636807`.

I would like to have a function that can convert Uint8Arr[n] into its equivalent integer and return the result in decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution will solve for Uint8Arr of any length.

```
function convert(Uint8Arr) {
    var length = Uint8Arr.length;

    let buffer = Buffer.from(Uint8Arr);
    var result = buffer.readUIntBE(0, length);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I found this solution extremely helpful, but I needed to convert from `Uint8Array[16]` and needed the following change to get it to work:

```
let result = buffer.readUInt32BE(0);
```

Comment: just a note that `length` argument in `readUIntBE`, which specifies a number of bytes to read, must satisfy `0 < byteLength <= 6`. Doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufreaduintbeoffset-bytelength).

Comment: more "manual" way, which should work fine is here: `parseInt(buffer.toString('hex',0,7),16)`. In the first step, buffer is converted to string, using 'hex' encoding, start and stop byte (0 and 7). Then `parseInt` is used to convert this hex number into decimal...

Answer (score 10):

For those who want little-endian, you can specify endianness using the [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) class.

```js
let buff = new Uint8Array(4);
buff[0]=0x12;
buff[1]=0x19;
buff[2]=0x21;
buff[3]=0x47;
var view = new DataView(buff.buffer, 0);
view.getUint32(0, true); // true here represents little-endian
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
let Uint8Arr = new Uint8Array(4);

Uint8Arr[0]=0x12;
Uint8Arr[1]=0x19;
Uint8Arr[2]=0x21;
Uint8Arr[3]=0x47;

let buffer = Buffer.from(Uint8Arr);

console.log( buffer.readUInt32BE(0) );
```